# Loaded Simultaneously in Parallel?

Tags: javascript, apache

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/b.js"></script>
```

I have two simple JS scripts, loaded in the above order. *a.js* has a reference to a function e.g. `foo()` in *b.js* i.e. *a.js* invokes `foo()` that is defined in *b.js*. On some servers, an error was thrown because `foo()` isn't recognized when *a.js* is executed; on some other machines, no error was thrown.

Do those two scripts loaded simultaneously in parallel? Or, in sequence? Does the answer depend on the architecture of the servers (e.g. multi-core, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: They're loaded and executed in order (if async isn't specified). It's strange that it doesn't fail always (anyway it depends on the client). Include first what you'll use (like you would do in any "standard" language).

Comment: Does this (i.e. failing, but not all the time) have something to do with function _hoisting_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downloads may or may not be in parallel (depending on the browser), but parsing of the scripts are in the sequence they are laid on the page.

if you used that order (`a.js` before `b.js`), with `foo()` declared in `b.js` but called in `a.js`, this will result in an error because `foo()` was called before it existed.

It's the same reason why JS libraries encourage you to load their scripts before any user scripts. That way, their references exist before you use them.