# Named vs. Anonymous Function: Identical?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)
>   [What is the difference between these 2 function syntax types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375150/what-is-the-difference-between-these-2-function-syntax-types)

In JavaScript, we can define a function, which will be called at a later time, using one of the methods below. That is, using a named function and assigning an anonymous function to a variable.

```
function myAdd(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}
myAdd(3, 2);

var mySubtract = function (a, b) {
    console.log(a - b);
}
mySubtract(3, 2);
```

Are they basically *always* identical? By identical, I mean no special contexts that might make them different. For example, it turns out [multiple left-hand assignment has some subtleties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758912) that might lead to a different result depending on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function declaration is hoisted (and can be used everywhere in the scope), the function expression will be available only after the assignment.

Comment: Does function _hoisting_ also apply to multiple files? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10511845/583539

Comment: No, different scripts are executed independently. See your answers there